# Is code completion for string values in JSON files possible?

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema, code-completion

I'm currently working with JSON files and exploring the possibility of implementing code completion specifically for string values within these files. To provide context, if I break it down, my JSON structure could look like the following:

```
{
  "$schema": "./schemas/example.schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "definition": "root/node1/subnode3/container2/parameter1",
  "value": "true"
}
```

The key definition is of type string and is the one I would be interested for the completion feature.

My IDE provides a keyboard shortcut for suggestions for the keys like "version" and "definition" but obviously by default not for the path string that would be possible for the definition key.

I want to inject the Path tree that I have available into the JSON schema to provide the possibility for the IDE to suggest valid paths e.g. for the definition value. Is that possible for standard JSON files?

I got the hint to set up a separate JSON acting like a kind of Database:

```
[
  "root/node1/subnode1",
  "root/node1/subnode2",
  "root/node1/subnode3",
  "root/node2/subnode1/container1",
  "root/node2/subnode1/container2",
  "root/node2/subnode2",
  "root/node2/subnode3/container1",
  "root/node2/subnode3/container2/parameter1",
  "root/node2/subnode3/container2/parameter2"
]
```

and then incorporate that into my original JSON file schema:

```
"definition": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "The definition path.",
            "autocomplete": true,
            "autocompletePath": "./myDatabase.json"
          }
```

but that did not work as intended.